# Car return / relocation services in the USA?

Tags: usa, car-rentals

When people rent cars one-way, the car rental company needs to return the car.  In countries such as Sweden, Norway, Australia, New Zealand, those cars are listed online and people can rent the car very cheaply or for free, provided that they move it from A to B within a specified time and don't make big detours.  Is there any such service in the USA?

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8373, though standbylocations.com is now http://www.imoova.com/ .

Comment: @choster Make that an answer!

Answer (score 4):

In the US these are typically known as driveaway services. Many allow for any licensed driver to participate, but some hire drivers and are not open for public participation.

A [typical example](http://www.autodriveaway.com/driver) of such a service requires that drivers deposit a small bond (security deposit) and, for foreign drivers, bring a copy of their driving record from their home country. The [deposit is returned to you](http://www.gonomad.com/1562-driveaway-across-the-usa-auto-driveaways) after you drop off the car at the destination.

A few examples of driveaway services I was able to find:

- [Auto Driveaway](http://www.autodriveaway.com/) (the largest such company in the US)
- [Cars to Florida](http://www.carstoflorida.com) (specializes in Canada-Florida round trips)
- [Bennett Driveaway](http://www.bennettdriveawayservices.com/) (commercial vehicles and trucks)
- [Canada DriveAway](http://www.canadadriveaway.com/) (Canada / USA vehicle relocation)

Answer (score 3):

There are a few. Each will come with their own terms and conditions, so check carefully (eg do you have to pay for some or all of the fuel, what about insurance, etc):

- [$1 relocations with VroomVroom](http://deals.vroomvroomvroom.com.au/)
- [Standbycars with imoova](http://www.imoova.com/)

and if you want an RV:

- [RV Relocations](http://www.rvrelocations.com/)