# Renting a car from Detroit to Tennessee or Florida

Tags: usa, automobiles, rental, florida, michigan

I'm in Michigan and I'd like to get to Tennessee or Florida. My idea is to go by car but when I see what the rentals cost (one way is immensely more expensive and I won't be going back north myself), It feels kind of pricey.

Is there a cheaper option? I've googled to see if I can find a web site with one way cars (someone who wants his delivered, for instance) but haven't been lucky with that.

Suggestions?

Comment: Related: [Car return / relocation services in the USA?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/28891/3221) In particular you may find Cars to Florida useful if you're willing to head up to Toronto to pick up a car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are Drive Away services that match drivers with vehicles that need to be driven to a specified destination.  A quick web search for "drive away services" will turn up number of these companies.  These services usually don't charge rental fees, you just fill up the gas as you go.  Most do require some sort of security, such as a cash deposit or credit card authorization hold.

BUT most of these deals have time restrictions, ie you have XX days to get the car/van/RV from point A to point B.  As such they might not be suited for your needs if you plan to stop and explore as you go.

Comment: I'll be googling *drive away* shortly. Let's hope tehre's something appropriate.